# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification problems in iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` to handle showing and hiding of the keyboard. Everything works perfect if I run it on iOS8 simulator/device, but it's causing me headaches on iOS9 simulator/device. Before I go into details of my problems, I must add that if I use `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, everything works like a charm.

**Problem 1:**

I have a `UIScrollView`, which contains multiple `UITextField`s. I use the following code:

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    NSNumber *rate = aNotification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:rate.floatValue animations:^{
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, kbSize.height);
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];    
    }];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

When I use this code on iOS9 device, the scroll view doesn't scroll to the point I want it to, but scrolls just beneath the text field that is first responder at the moment, instead. However, when I click on another text field after that, it scrolls to the desired point.

**Problem 2:**

I have a `UICollectionView`, which contains one `UITextField` and uses flow layout. The code is the same as above, except for the setting of the contentOffset, for which I use:

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

When I use this code on iOS9 device, the `contentInset` is set to exactly twice the size it should be. It looks as if it is being set twice - once automatically and the once again because of my code, despite the `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` setting. One more thing to add to my second problem - if I leave out the setting of the `contentInset` in my code, it is set to the correct value on iOS9 device, but of course remains 0.0 on iOS8 device.

Is there something I'm not seeing or is this some sort of a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, that works, which is to dispatch to the main queue. I also removed `UIView animateWithDuration: completion:` method, so the code now looks like this:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.collectionView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        self.collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:2 inSection:2];
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    });
}
```